# How can I retrieve particular data from json string using Apex?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, parsing

When individuals fill out a survey through an outside source, the JSON data gets stored in Salesforce as a Long Text Area in a custom Survey__c object (about 25,000 characters).
There are hundreds of questions asked, and I would like to store only a few particular responses as a field on the Survey__c.  For example, questions 322 and 340.

I need to create a utility that can be used in a trigger for future incoming Survey__c records, as well as used in a Batch so that we can update fields for existing Survey__c records.

I have no idea how to parse the data just to get the particular "Q322" and "Q340" values.  I have been reading into how to parse JSON using Apex, and keep seeing information about creating maps of all the values - is this necessary if I only need a few out of the hundreds?

I have tried using things like JSON2Apex, but I don't think I understand enough about Apex to tell what it was really doing or how to take advantage of it.

I suppose I hardly know how to get started with this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to expose the JSON for us to give you more guidance

Comment: @cropredy ok, I've added it as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File processing is a complicated topic in any language. Each file has specific protocols that favor some characteristic. For example, movie files often include metadata that makes it easy to seek to a specific frame or time in the movie, and image files often have properties to make it possible to know how much memory to allocate to the rendered image. JSON follows specific rules, and those rules can't be violated if it is valid JSON. This means that, at minimum, the entire JSON string has to be parsed for correctness.

However, if you don't need all that extra data, simply don't use it. The JSON parser doesn't care about extra data unless it's in strict mode. It's perfectly fine to have a class that has just the information you want. I'll show a simple example here.

```
class Demo {
    public String message;
}
Demo x = (Demo)JSON.deserialize('{"message":"Hello World","garbage":"Other Data"}', Demo.class);
System.debug(x.message);
```

Here, I get the message "Hello World", while "garbage" is simply ignored. The JSON must still be valid, but it's code I didn't have to write since I didn't care. This isn't always possible, though; if your data is organized a certain way, you may very well be forced to create a design that includes data you don't care about. In most cases, that's probably okay, since most requests aren't terribly big to begin with.

The caveat here is simply that without knowing what your JSON looks like, it's impossible to tell you how much data you "need" to process. You might have a design like this, or you might need something radically more complex. That said, you can certainly try to pare down the amount of code you need to write, though I wouldn't recommend wasting too much time doing so. JSON2Apex is a favorite tool of mine, it gets the job done in a timely manner most of the time.

Comment: Thank you!  This definitely pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up 'beautifying' the json and used
"        Util_JsonParser parJSON = Util_JSONParser.createParser(json);
        Object result = parJSON.get('result').Value;
        String res = String.ValueOf(result);"
To get deeper into the json, eventually retrieving the value I needed which was just a step or two deeper.